# create sequence number with a defined started number and length vba

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to define some specific id numbers in VBA/Macro. When the user types in a message box a specific number 100 and the length of the number 11. The outcome should be 100,101,...,110. Really appreciate.

```
Expected Result=SEQUENCE(11,1,1000000,1)
```

Comment: Did you try `WorksheetFunction.Sequence` yet, as I prompted to your previous question? It's not clear where you want the outcome btw.

Comment: yeah, thanks. I am trying to add a message box too, to make it user friendly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62034613/generate-1n-sequence-array

Comment: To get user input, you can use a flavor of an **input** box (`InputBox` or `Application.InputBox`). Please describe in more detail the whole process you have in mind, from getting the first, then the second number, to the cells (e.g. a column or row starting with the selected (active) cell) where the result should be written. Add the information to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idGenerator prompts the user to type the base and the counter separated by one of [,./ -]. If the input is not valid reprompt until the user escape or type valid numbers. The function returns an 1D array with the IDs. After as you can see in my example we can write the array in any position in a sheet horizontally or vertically

```
Sub testGenerator()
   Dim rslt As Variant
   rslt = idGenerator()
   If LBound(rslt) = 0 Then Exit Sub
   With Application.WorksheetFunction
'IF YOU WANT TO COPY THE ARRAY IN ROWS
      Range("H2").Resize(UBound(rslt), 1) = .Transpose(rslt)
     
'IF YOU WANT TO COPY THE ARRAY IN COLUMNS
      Range("I2").Resize(1, UBound(rslt)) = rslt 
   End With
End Sub


Public Function idGenerator() As Variant()
   Dim answ As Variant, c As Long, ch As String, p As Long, gtmp As String, ctmp As String
   Dim idBase As Long, counter As Long, rslt() As Variant
   Const separ = "-./, "
   Const msg = "Please type the ID base and the count" & vbCrLf & "separated by space or one of: / , . -"
   'if lbound(idGenerator)  eq 0 => no user input
   ReDim idGenerator(0 To 0)
Linput:
   answ = Trim(InputBox(msg, "ID GENERATOR"))
   If answ = "" Then Exit Function
   For c = Len(separ) To 1 Step -1
      ch = Mid$(separ, c, 1)
      p = InStr(1, answ, ch)
      If p > 0 Then
         GoTo Lgen
      End If
   Next
   Call MsgBox(msg, vbCritical)
   GoTo Linput
Lgen:
   gtmp = Trim(Left(answ, p - 1))
   ctmp = Trim(Mid$(answ, p + 1))
   If Not (IsNumeric(gtmp) And IsNumeric(ctmp)) Then
      MsgBox ("Please for Id and count type only mumbers" & vbCrLf & "separated by space or one of: / , . -")
      GoTo Linput
   End If
   idBase = CLng(gtmp)
   counter = CLng(ctmp)
   ReDim rslt(1 To counter)
   For c = 1 To counter
      rslt(c) = idBase + c - 1
   Next
   idGenerator = rslt
End Function
```